# django queryset - hitting the db in O(1)

Tags: python, database, django, complexity-theory, django-queryset

I have the following line in my Django app:

```
last_job_instance = (JobInstance.objects.filter(job_type = job_type).filter(agent = agent).order_by('-execution_end_date'))[0]
```

I want this to run in O(1) time - or in another words - I want to pull out of the database only the last job instance according to its date.

My question is the above queryset hit the database once, or first get all the job instances objects, order them by date and only then get me the first one (which is O(nlogn) ).

Many thanks !

Tidhar

Comment: you can check it yourself by doing `print JobInstance.objects.filter(job_type = job_type).filter(agent = agent).order_by('-execution_end_date').query`

Comment: I'd love it if my database could return ordered query results in O(1) :)

Comment: Look into clustered indexes for your database if you are interested in speeding up access on the database end.

Comment: From what I understood, OP is asking if there is 1 query involved, or is there some post-processing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `latest("execution_end_date")` on your queryset:

```
lji = JobInstance.objects.filter(job_type=job_type, agent=agent).latest('execution_end_date')
```

Or add it to your model's Meta class like so:

```
class JobInstance(models.Model):

    ....

    class Meta:
        get_latest_by = "execution_end_date"
```